# How can I get the current user's id in forms.py in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want current user's id on my forms.py because i am trying to compare user's wallet balance and user's entered amount if balance is less i want to show error message otherwise success message
so how can i get current user's id on forms.py in django

Answer (score 0):

request object has reference to user.

To check if user is authenticated.

```
request.user.is_authenticated()
```

to get user object;

```
request.user
```

Comment: is there way to auto add this with form ?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the form's `__init__` method to accept the user.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

In your form's methods, you can now access `self.user`

Then you need to update your view to include the user when you instantiate the form, for example:

```
form = MyForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
```